# Combining topic based ROS2 control, and DiffBot demo

Tags: ros2-control

I have built a working HW component for my diff drive bot, based on [ROS2 control demo 2](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/tree/humble/example_2). I also implemented a ROS2 node in a separate header file, for communicating with my micro-controller running Micro-ROS.

I was adviced to not run any node inside a HW interface, and instead try the [topic based ROS2 control package](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/topic_based_ros2_control). I have installed the `apt` package, but do not fully understand how this should be combined with my existing HW component.

In principle, the topic based HW interface "does the same thing" regarding communication, as my existing interface. Asking naively: should the two interfaces co-exist?

Answer (score 1):

It is a general advice not to use a node inside a ros2_control hardware_component, but if it does not harm your real-time requirements for sure you can do it -> Adapt the `topic_based_ros2_control` code to match your requirements to have a single hardware component for your system (no co-existing ones).

Comment: Cool, thanks again :) However, if I do replace my existing interface, I struggle to see the difference. They both have a `rclcpp::Node` as a private member of the HW interface class.

Comment: Maybe there is no difference, I don't know your implementation ;) Maybe you can use it directly as it is.

Comment: Do you consider https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/topic_based_ros2_control/blob/37a98e652818ac4b884786558a2f3c0373415c16/include/topic_based_ros2_control/topic_based_system.hpp#L71 to be a node "inside" the HW interface?

Comment: yes, because it uses it in the [read/write methods](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/topic_based_ros2_control/blob/37a98e652818ac4b884786558a2f3c0373415c16/src/topic_based_system.cpp#L330) (which are running in the realtime-task)

Comment: interesting, that is what my HW interface does as well. So in practical terms, the package does not really solve the inherent problem with topic based ROS2 control?

Answer (score 0):

> In principle, the topic based HW interface "does the same thing" regarding communication, as my existing interface.

This is not correct. It's a bad idea to look at robot-arm control examples if you want to do wheeled-robot control. ros2_control brings a lot of features you may or may not need. For a wheeled robot, the input to ros2_control is a Twist, and the output is a proprietary command to the motor controller (typically a rotation-velocity target for each driven wheel.)

Comment: The hardware component exports hardware interfaces of type position, velocity etc.. only the controller claiming those interfaces is very different as you say.

Comment: sloppy formulation, apologies. I guess what I was trying to convey, was the observation that both interfaces declares a `rclcpp::Node` as a private member of the interface class

Comment: "both interfaces declares a rclcpp::Node" - if you intend to use ros2_control, those are crappy examples. Maybe useful if you want to roll your own minimalist thing.