# ros2 humble with arduino uno

Tags: ros2, arduino, ros-humble, ros2-controllers

I am trying to do serial communication with arduino uno with ros2 humble, i have tried something with micro-ros and it didn't work. There are no clear instructions on how to do it. I just want to push some data to arduino uno and when uno receives it send a signal to ros2 saying that it received data. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the serial communication without micro-ros, see [this video by Articulated Robotics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J02jEKawE5U). [This is another example](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_14/doc/userdoc.html) how to setup a communication pipeline outside of ROS.

For using micro ROS, you maybe only need a topic-based hardware component instead of a custom one, see: [Combining topic based ROS2 control, and DiffBot demo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104878/combining-topic-based-ros2-control-and-diffbot-demo)